# Limit number of values group_by is returning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

`Category` has a many-to-one relationship to `Post`.

I'm grouping posts in hashes, in groups by each category with the following code:

```
posts.group_by {|post| post.category}
```

But how do I limit the number of posts, to e.g. six posts per category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
posts.group_by(&:category).map { |category, posts| [category, posts.take(6)] }
```

Comment: Seems to work brilliantly. Just a questions though, if the posts in the original `posts` collection has a certain order - is there any risk that `.map` don't respect that order and doesn't pick the *first* six posts?

Comment: You can add an order by before map.
`posts.group_by(&:category).order(:name).map { |category, posts| [category, posts.take(6)] }`

Comment: @uri-agassi I wonder if you could explain what the map bit is doing in plain English. So…

    Grab POSTS and GROUP them by CATEGORY and then…

Comment: @MatthewBennett - ... take the first 6 posts of each category

Comment: @uri-agassi Yeah :-). I guess I was wondering why "category" and "posts" needed to be repeated so often in the statement. Or is that just how map works?

Comment: well, in the closure, they are just parameters, you could shorten it to be `posts.group_by(&:category).map { |c, p| [c, p.take(6)] }` - but that would be considerably less readable...

Comment: @UriAgassi Thank you, you are life saver for me, but one more critical problem in my case is i want to serialize the both resource.

Comment: @Vishal - sorry, I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @UriAgassi Please check my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53373479/rails-add-serializer-for-group-by-resources